# How to access files loaded to sourceforge.net using via SFTP using HTTP

Tags: sftp, sourceforge

I loaded files to one of my projects web following their [documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/SFTP). Now I need to get the URL for those files so I can access them from my application. Sadly, I'm unable to find the URL format for this. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you uploaded your `index.html` to `/home/project-web/foo_project/htdocs/index.html` on `web.sourceforge.net`

You can than access it using `http://foo_project.sourceforge.net/index.html`

For details, see https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Project%20Web%20Services/

Note that the path SFTP documentation mentions, like `/home/groups/f/fo/foo_project/` is actually a link to `/home/project-web/foo_project/`.

Comment: My issue was that the files where not within the htdocs folder. Thanks a lot!